# Cant create a new Produkt - Error at Auto-Generate Meta-Information

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

When i try to create a new Product, i cant save the product of couse an Error on the Auto-Generate Meta-Information Site.

Error-Code(my free translation :P )

```
The Value of the Attributes "Auto-Generate Meta-Information" must be uniquely.
```

Error-Code (in German)

```
Der Wert des Attributes "Auto-Generate Meta-Information" muss einmalig sein.
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to german language forum

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute Auto-Generate Meta-Information which should have a unique value..
I am guessing there is already a product in magento which is having the same value....

> Please try entering some other value for the attribute "Auto-Generate Meta-Information" and try saving the product again ..

Comment: I try to! but i can only choose between "Yes" and "No" and the error occurs in both variants